# How to Determine Resource-ID of the CMFCRibbonButton using NMHDR Structure?

Tags: visual-c++, mfc

**I implemented my own CMFCToolTipCtrl class in order to modify enhanced tooltip in Ribbon Control.But I'm unable to determine Resource ID from NMHDR Structure.How to get it ?**

//////////////////////////////
MainApp.cpp
//////////////////////////////

CMFCToolTipInfo ttParams;

ttParams.m_bVislManagerTheme =FALSE;

theApp.GetTooltipManager()->SetTooltipParams(AFX_TOOLTIP_TYPE_ALL,
        RUNTIME_CLASS(MTP_CMFCToolTipCtrl), &ttParams);

//////////////////////////////
MTP_CMFCToolTipCtrl.cpp
//////////////////////////////

BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP(MTP_CMFCToolTipCtrl, CMFCToolTipCtrl)
    ON_NOTIFY_REFLECT(TTN_SHOW, OnShow)
    ON_WM_SETFOCUS()
END_MESSAGE_MAP()

void MTP_CMFCToolTipCtrl::OnShow(NMHDR* pNMHDR, LRESULT* pResult)

{

int m_nCurrID=?

// How to Determine Resource-ID of the CMFCRibbonButton using NMHDR-structure ??

switch (m_nCurrID)
    {

```
case ID_EDIT_PASTE:
    SetDescription (_T("paste button description..."));
    break;

case ID_EDIT_CUT:
    SetDescription (_T("cut button description..."));
    break;

default:
    SetDescription (_T (""));

}

CMFCToolTipCtrl::OnShow (pNMHDR, pResult);
```

}

Comment: The ID of your Control is not TTN_SHOW?

Comment: @ Sunscreen  
Could not get u please explain in brief.

Comment: i  tried  many different casting with NMHDR structure but nothing seems to work.. help me out..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

problem  solved..by implementing

CMFCToolBarImages* CMainFrame::GetTooltipImage(UINT uiID)
         {}                //     in Main.cpp

CSize MTP_CMFCToolTipCtrl::GetIconSize()

{

CMFCToolBarImages* pBmp = ((CMainFrame*)GetTopLevelFrame())->GetTooltipImage(m_nID);

................

................

}

...for more help please refer MSOffice2007Demo sample of MFC Feature Pack 2008.... thank you.. :|